# DocumentViewer Zooming/Panning

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The DocumentViewer has a native Zoom feature with only two +/- buttons.
Now i'm wondering if there is a way to access the Zoom property so i can make a slider out of it ie.(Zoom: 150%)

Another feature which i expected it to have is the Hand Tool panning that most PDF viewers have natively so users could view other parts without scrolling. Could anyone provide me a way to develop such a feature? A custom control template perhaps?